# Building an element with jQuery gets me an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an element with jQuery, which contains text from an input field after the user clicks the SUBMIT button.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2y26rzot/

Here is my javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('button[type=submit]').click(function () {
            var typedText = $('input[type=text]').val();
            var resultText = $('<p></p>').text(typedText+'2');
            $('section.result').append(resultText);
            console.log(typedText);
            alert(typedText);
            console.log(resultText);
            alert(resultText);
        });
    });
```

I have included bootstrap js and css and of course jQuery as well.
The problem occurs somewhere between the first and the second alert, but I have no idea where and why. I have basic understanding of jQuery, as I learned it by doing, so I may be getting something wrong here.

The error on my local machine reads:

> text
>
> index.html:45 [p, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector:
> "", toArray: function, get: function…]
>
> Navigated to file:///C:/Users//Desktop/textonbackground/index.html?

Of course if I remove the last 2 lines with the resultText console log and alert I don't get an error, but the text still vanishes and I don't understand why. Can someone explain this to me and of course suggest some other way to achieve my goal, namely to get information from the input field and post it as a paragraph on the page.

I should mention that I've tried different approaches building the variables and appending the text (with .add and .after) but nothing changed. I am missing something here.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your fiddle shows no errors in Chrome, nor can I see anything immediately wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text disappears because the page refreshes after form submission. The problem is not in `.text()`

If you add `e.preventDefault()` to it, the text will stay where it should.

If you don't want to change the event, you could use a regular button (`<button type="button">`) without the `form`

Online here: http://jsfiddle.net/2y26rzot/3/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks, I noticed that too late )) lucky the problem is not with `.text()`

Comment: As a side not if you use the `submit` method of a form, you can simply write the word and press `enter` ) I would vote for using that instead of `click`

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine in the fiddle, you just need to prevent the default action of the form submitting (if it submits it will refresh the page and so your clientside changes, ie. the changes made with js, will not show):

```
    $('button[type=submit]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...rest of code
    });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2y26rzot/2/)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to append a p element, with a text inside, you should bascalliy do

```
var resultText = $('<p>'+typedText+'2</p>');
```

Because .text() returns either the text of the concerned element if you dont pass any argument (to get text), or the jquery object of the concerned element if you pass an argument (to set text)

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP's approach won't work?

Comment: No, it can work, it's just quite complicated for a simple thing. It's like opening a banana with a chainsaw, where it can be easily done with your bare hands

Comment: @Robin, let's consider that `typedText` contains characters among `<`, `>` or `&` and speak of chainsaws again :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi True :)